# How can I loosen stiff piriformis and iliopsoas using a myofascial release technique without dry needling?

Tags: stretching, hip

Due to flat feet and leg length asymmetry I have , my right piriformis and iliopsoas is almost always stiff. I discovered this issue at an age of 29 and the issue is being solved by foot insoles which already help tremendously.

Currently, I visit my physician once in 2 to 3 weeks for a dry needling session to loosen the gluteal area. After each session, my hips are somehow re-stationed well. After a year of treatment till now, my deadlift sessions (started at 4 reps 22,5kg of 1RM: 30kg) end up with a PR at 90% of my 1RM (8 reps of 102,5kg 1RM: 142,5kg).

I have tried to loosen those trigger points in the problem area with a- foamroll, 8kg medicine ball, lacrosse ball, golf ball, large marble and etc... but somehow no matter how hard try, doesn't work as well as dry needling. Sometimes the muscles don't even budge even after 20 minutes of focussed pressure. Of course I make sure to react to pain when necessary and stop the attempt when it is uncomfortable.

P.S.: I always do my release attempt symmetrical, so whenever I attempt to release, I try it on both sides to prevent future imbalances.

Any ideas how to cope with this?

I tried [Don Tigny's SIJ exercises](http://thelowback.com/fix.htm#exercises) and as refered in [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12705/hip-stretches-recover-from-piriformis-syndrome-and-hard-gluteal-muscles), and also [PNF stretch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRMlfbDZGgE) for a while and it helped me maintain the status quo.

I want to give a try to Pavel Tsatsouline's beyond stretching, but I wanna prepare for it first and don't want to go further while I am having this annoying challenge.

Answer (score 2):

I also suffer with periformis tightness due to an imbalance, and I find if I sit on the foam roller with legs bent. I take 1 foot across the other knee and can usually wriggle about on the roller to get to the spot that hurts.

Have you tried in this position?

[image: https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRldKujh8zIOsR3-wX2xtTO2-QHVo7JA8Wa3lnmPYR0X7PpAD0w]

Comment: I tried it today and it worked on the left side. Right side still won't budge. Btw, that is the shorter leg. Do you also pull the knee inwards for stretching or push it outwards to do resisted stretching while you adhere the foamroll wriggle?

Comment: Hi glad it worked on your left side.  This might be because your shorter side is tighter.  I tend to just sit  in that position and not really use it as a stretch. It is quite a good stretch if you do the same thing lying on your back and pushing the knee away if you know what I mean?  I'm sure I can find an image to post if you need one.  Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Bought a Supernova from Rogue sports and it bears wonders. Also cleaning up the hamstring insertions to glutes and and glutes themselves helped much more.